# Delphi TIdHTTPServer: not allowed to load local resourse from remote device

Tags: javascript, delphi, remote-access, indy, httpserver

I'm making a VCL Forms Application with a TIdHTTPServer on the main form and a CommandGet of the IdHTTPServer procedure:

```
procedure TForm6.IdHTTPServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  indexStream: TFileStream;
  path, indexPath: string;
begin
  AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'UTF-8';
  path := GetCurrentDir.Remove(GetCurrentDir.Length - Length('Win32\Debug'));
  ARequestInfo.Document := path + 'scripts/script1.js';
  ARequestInfo.Document := path + 'scripts/script2.js';

  if pos('profile', ARequestInfo.UnparsedParams) > 0 then
  begin
    indexPath := path + 'index.html';  
    AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TFileStream.Create(indexPath, fmOpenReadWrite);
  end;
end;
```

**EDIT**

```
procedure TForm6.IdHTTPServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
   ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  applicationDirectory: string;
begin
  AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'UTF-8';
  AResponseInfo.FreeContentStream := True;
  applicationDirectory := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)
    .Remove(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName).Length -
    Length('Win32\Debug') - 1);
  AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TFileStream.Create(applicationDirectory +
     'scripts/script1.js', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TFileStream.Create(applicationDirectory +
     'scripts/script2.js', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);

  if pos('profile&userName=', ARequestInfo.UnparsedParams) > 0 then
  begin
    AResponseInfo.ContentStream :=
       TFileStream.Create(applicationDirectory + 'index.html', fmOpenRead);
  end;
  // other requests
end;
```

Here is the content of index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Profile</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="[app-path]/scripts/script1.js "></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="[app-path]/scripts/script2.js "></script>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- Page content -->
  </body>
</html>
```

When I start the application and access `http://localhost/?profile&userName=testUser` it works fine but when I start the application and type in other computer's chrome browser `http://{my-ip4-address}/?profile&userName=testUser` I get two messages: 'Not allowed to load local resource: file:///{app_path}/scripts/script1.js', 'Not allowed to load local resource: file:///{app_path}/scripts/script2.js. The content of the HTML page is visible.

**EDIT**

Based on the comments and answer `index.html` changed to

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Profile</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/script1.js "></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/script2.js "></script>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- Page content -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Editing my code like this I can access files but the problem is that the content of script1.js is same as the content of script2.js. Any idea how to send the files correctly.

Comment: put your script2.js to the server and load it from there. The server `http://{my-ip4-address}` does not know anything of your computers file path.

Comment: @moskito-x which property of the httpServer should I use to put a file to the server

Comment: @mitko.berbatov : the same way you put `index.html` to the server.

Comment: @moskito-x when I put script1.js to the server the file is empty. Why this happens.

Comment: Please edit the question not in a way, so the context, between the question and answer is no longer recognizable. I have edited them to the previous version.

Comment: Look at your `index.html` there you load `script1.js` twice.

Comment: Checked it: index.html is fine

Comment: Then your `index.html` and the file you are **showing us** are different here.

Comment: I edited the question and index.html file :)

Answer (score 3):

Never use the application path (`[app-path]` in your example HTML code) if the HTML file is going to be served to other computers. For local stand-alone HTML pages this might work, but external clients will not be able to access that resource.

Instead, specify the path to the JavaScript (absolute as `/scripts/script1.js` or relative like `scripts/script1.js`, depending on the virtual directory structure) and resolve it to the file on the server based on the Request.Document property.

Your example code nevers read the Request.Document property (and even assigns values to it - twice!). So the server does not know which resource the client actually wants.

Your code must transform the Document property into a path relative to a document root folder, which might be a dedicated subfolder of your applications working directory for example. And then check if this path points to an existing file. If it exists, read it and return its content. If it does not exist, return an error code.

Comment: You also need to set `AResponseInfo.ContentType` to an appropriate value, don't rely on the default (which is `text/html`). And get rid of `GetCurrentDir()`, its value changes dynamically during the course of the app's lifetime. If you want the path where the app is running, use `ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)` instead. And get rid of the logic that strips `Win32\Debug` from that path, since that subfolder won't exist anymore once you deploy your app to another machine.

Comment: @mjn I edited my code (see the edited question) and I can access files but the problem is that the content of script1.js is same as the content of script2.js.

Comment: Let me answer with a question: if you write `x := 1; x := 2;`, which value would you expect x to have after executing it? Then look at the assignments to the response content stream in your Delphi code.

Comment: fixed it using ARequestInfo.RawHTTPCommand to send the file required. Thanks for help @mjn